# Excel cannot access to ssas cube

Tags: excel, ssas

Hello everyone,

I encounter random problems concerning the access to the cube ssas via excel.
when I connect to the cube via SSMS, access via Excel is unlocked and becomes functional.
here is the error message when it is blocked:

Errors in the metadata manager. An error occurred while loading "DatabasePermission" Database permision, from file "\? \ D: \ MSAS13.CEGIBI \ OLAP \ Data \ Bi_AnalysisServices.111.db \ DatabasePermission.2.perm.xml"

is there a solution to this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could try running the [DBCC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/database-consistency-checker-dbcc-for-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762) command. But ultimately I expect you will need to delete the Analysis Services database and redeploy from the source code. That error indicates some files in the deployed database are corrupt.

Comment: Interesting to note that DBCC can be run against SSAS as well. Always thought it is for SQL Server alone. Thanks for sharing